# Why are theese registers first set to Zero?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Looking at fast PWM Modes, I found this sample on how to set it up:

```
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
TCCR2B = _BV(CS22);
```

[here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM)

In a magnetic levitaiton code sample the author wants to set the timer fast pwm mode, but they start off by defining the registers to 0, like this:

```
   // Timer 2 register: WGM20 sets PWM phase correct mode, COM2x1 sets the PWM out to channels A and B.
   TCCR2A = 0;
   TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM20);
   // Set the prescaler to 8, the PWM freq is 16MHz/255/2/<prescaler>
   TCCR2B = 0;
   TCCR2B = _BV(CS21);
```

why?

Comment: They are not variables, they are registers. Please look up the data sheet.

Comment: In an example I found `TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21);` and this line does not set the register, it OR's it. Hence clearing is first.